# is there anyway to automate password reset process in shell? without escape characters?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Team,
we have certain activity every 90 days, to reset passwords on multiple host.
Now my query is:

My password contains special characters, is there any mini shell script that can help to find existing password in file and replace with value mention in my any other txt file on same host?

e.g.  oldfile.txt (contain old password at anywhere in file)
newfile.properties (contain new password to replace that in oldfile.txt)

I know its very tough task to do escaping every password string
values, is there any way we can place as it is password from newfile
to oldfile as mention above?

Thanks,

Comment: You shouldn't have your password in plaintext in a file

Answer (score 0):

Use `chpasswd`.  It reads stdin with one or more lines containing `username:password` and changes the password(s) for those username(s) accordingly.

If the passwords are un-encrypted, it will encrypt them.

`chpasswd`'s `-e` option is useful if the passwords are already encrypted (highly recommended, it's never a good idea to store passwords as plain text)

You can use `sed` or `awk` or `perl` or any other convenient tool/scripting language to output the usernames and passwords in the `username:password` format required by `chpasswd`.

See `man chpasswd` for more details.

Comment: THanks for reply, but I want to change it via shell process, not linux inbuilt functionality or changing linux username password, it is service account passwords, used by 3rd party connecting systems. So I mentioned those in properties file and it should replaced with destination like that